# Does Fubini's Theorem hold when an unbounded linear operator is used in the integrand?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

According to [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) we may (under "normal" circumstances) assert that:

$$
\int_{X \times Y} f(x, y) \mathrm{d}(x, y)=\int_{X}\left(\int_{Y} f(x, y) \mathrm{d} y\right) \mathrm{d} x=\int_{Y}\left(\int_{X} f(x, y) \mathrm{d} x\right) \mathrm{d} y
$$

which, when applied in the context of function multiplication within the integrand presumably implies:

$$
\int_Y \left ( \int_X f(x) \mathrm{d}x \right) g(y) \mathrm{d}y = \int_X \left( \int_Y g(y) \mathrm{d}y \right) f(x) \mathrm{d}x
$$

**Problem:** Apparently (see below) this is *not* the case if we insert an unbounded linear operator into the integrand:

$$
\int_Y \left ( \int_X U(f(x)) \mathrm{d}x \right) g(y) \mathrm{d}y = \int_X \left( \int_Y g(y) \mathrm{d}y \right) U(f(x)) \mathrm{d}x \color{red}{\text{ (fails to hold)}}
$$

where the condition for linear operator $L$ to be unbounded is that there does not exist some $M \ge 0$ such that for all vectors $x$

$$
\|Lx\| \leq M \|x\|,\,
$$

But is this true? And if so, why?

**Context.** This question arose as the result of [another question from the area of quantum mechanics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194796/why-does-omega-ij-overline-omega-ji-only-imply-omega-is-hermitian) (which I offered 2 bounties on, but never felt I got a satisfactory answer). A couple of the answers offered asserted the result above, but I didn't feel were given any sort of justification, so I'm trying to understand with a new post.

Comment: Is there a typo? "this is not the case if we insert an **un**bounded linear operator"?

Comment: @angryavian: You're correct. Just fixed it.

Comment: You need to carefully check whether the conditions for Fubini's theorem are met or not. When the function is separable as $f(x)g(y)$, you need the joint function $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ to be absolutely integrable on $X \times Y$ (which I believe reduces to $f$ and $g$ being absolutely integrable on $X$ and $Y$ respectively, but I might be wrong).

Comment: Also what are the domain and range of $f, g, U$? I'm unclear on what $U(f(x))$ means; if $f$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$, then $U$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @angryavian. I think that it should be $Uf(x)=(Uf)(x).$

Comment: In the counter example in the linked discussion they use the operator $K=iD,$ where $D$ is differentiation. That is not even an operator on neither $L^1$ nor $L^2$.

Comment: Conversion of product integral to iterated integrals is valid when $X$, $Y$ are $\sigma$-finite and $f \in L^1(X \times Y)$ or $f$ is measurable and $f \colon X \times Y \to [0, \infty]$. In practice, to check whether $f \in L^1(X \times Y)$ you convert the integral of $|f|$ to an iterated integral.